# Which mechanic would be most appropriate

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

I've been struggling with the following problem.
There are two classes - Customer and Cart, related by the aggregation(?), that is Customer class has a private field of Cart within so a Cart can be assigned to a current Customer(user/owner). I want to implement another class - CheckOutMachine which main task will be customer settlement and then printing the bill.
The problem is I want to achieve that in two different ways that is something like

```
public class Main() {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 // creating necessary objects
 Customer customer = new Customer("James");
 Cart cart = new Cart();
 customer.setCart(cart);
 CheckOut checkOut = new CheckOut();

 // creating products, adding to the Cart
 // ...

 // customer settlement
 checkOut.checksOut(customer)
 checkOut.checksOut(cart)
 }
}
```

So two completely different objects as parameters with single method.
I am looking for a mechanic which will be the most appropriate in this scenario.
What came to my mind at first was generic types, but can't imagine implementation of it, it would be awesome to read your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If `Customer` and `Cart` have a useful (*) common superclass, you simply need a method which takes an instance of that class.

```
class CheckOut {
  void checksOut(TheCommonSuperClass param) { ... }
}
```

If they don't have a useful common superclass, have two overloads, one for each type.

```
class CheckOut {
  void checksOut(Customer customer) { ... }
  void checksOut(Cart cart) { ... }
}
```

---

(*) By "useful", I mean that the superclass provides methods to access the things you need in the `checksOut` method. Obviously, they will always have *a* common superclass (`java.lang.Object`), but that's not really useful for doing anything specific to your application.